# Whats the simplest and proper way to route in a template

Tags: vue.js, routes, quasar-framework

Instead of showing data from a component, I'm currently routing a user to login at `/account` if they are not `authorized`, by doing this:

```
<template>
  <q-card v-if="authorized">
    <q-card-section>
      <DataGrid/>
    </q-card-section>
  </q-card>
  <span v-else>
    {{ this.$router.push('/account') }}
  </span>
</template>
```

It's simple and works, but I'm not sure its really correct because although it pushes the user to where I want them to be, the console gets this error:

```
uncaught exception: undefined
```

(I'm currently on Quasar v1.9.14)

Basically I want to show the data if the user is authorized or redirect if they are not authorized, or become unauthorized later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simpler than I thought. <strike>I believe the answer is events.</strike> The span can simply change to:

<strike>`<span v-else @load="$router.push('/account')"/>`</strike>

```
<span v-else :class="authorized ? '' : $router.push('/account')"/>
```

1. Its even simpler because its a one liner
2. It will work even after `mounted()` has already fired and `authorized` becomes `false`
3. Actually, I now can delete similar logic in `mounted()` (DRY principle)

**EDITS**:
After proper testing I found it actually does not work with my first `@load` event example.

Comment: Although I haven't tried the way you suggest, you may, instead, want to do this logic in the `beforeRouteEnter` hook to avoid any UI "flashes" in the case of not authorized.

Comment: why are you using `$router.push` in a `:class`. Just use a watcher

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you do not need to use `this` in the template.

If you want to route them based on the `authorized` value, you could probably use a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers).

Alternatively, I would probably do something in `mounted` which checks if the user can be there. E.g.

```
async mounted ()
{
    const authorized = await fetch("something")
    if (!authorized)
    {
        this.$router.push('/account')
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the session determined? Is it not by sending something to the server to check if they've still got a valid session?

Comment: but what happens if, say I lose internet connection and session expires, what happens then?